# How to insert an image directly under a subsection title

Tags: graphics, overleaf

I am working with Overleaf. I have created a document with sections and subsections and I want to insert an image directly under the subsection.

I did it as follows:

```
\subsection{Title}

\begin{figure}[h]

\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Image}

\end{figure}
```

Somehow I see the title, but the image goes to the end of the document. How can i fix it, so that it goes exactly under the title?

Comment: Why are you using the figure environment, when you don't want the image to float? Just use `\includegraphics` wherever you want the image to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried @Juan A. Navarro's answer below:

```
%Available at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text#:~:text=The%20short%20answer%3A%20use%20the,H%5D%20option%20for%20your%20figure.&text=The%20longer%20answer%3A%20The%20default,how%20books%20are%20often%20typeset.  

\usepackage{float}%load this into your preamble

...

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Image}
\caption{Write some caption here}\label{image1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: ah perfect now it worked thanks a lot!!!

Comment: And do forget to accept it as answer if it solved your problem for the benefit of other users who may be experiencing this same problem.